# Sprinner is not showing up in IE 9 and IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

Js code

```
     $(settingsLink.selector).click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass("spinnerActive");
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
    });
```

and CSSS

```
 .spinnerActive {
       background: url('images/common/spinner.gif') no-repeat scroll 100% 50%;
  }
```

here on clikcing the link I am adding the class to parent element and displaying spinner from CSS,
its working fine in all browsers including IE8, But now working in IE 9  and IE 10,

When i Just add a alert like follow It starts working !!!!

```
    $(settingsLink.selector).click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass("spinnerActive");
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
        alert($(this).parent().attr('class'));
    });
```

whats going on here ? How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Do you have a class named disabled in your CSS ? Did you mean '$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');' ?

Comment: YE.. i have a class called 'disabled='

Comment: This is not a class but an attribute of your element so use $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');'

Comment: yes. But what is that stopping me to have class name as 'disabled'

Comment: Nothing. But you said 'disabled=' with the equal (=) sign. Do you have a .disabled {...} in your CSS file ? Could you post your HTMl plz ?